# getting KeyError: Adj. Close in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I encountering an error KeyError: 'Adj. Close'. And I'm not sure why,

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import math

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low', 'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume',]]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close'])/ df['Adj. Close'] * 
100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open'])/ df['Adj. Open'] * 
100.0

df = df[['Adj. Open','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]

forecast_col =  'Adj. Close'
df.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)

forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.1*len(df)))

df['label'] = df['Adj. Close'].shift(-forecast_out)

print(df.head())
```

There is this other error which goes like this

> File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\idlelib\google_stock.py", line 19, in 
>       df['label'] = df['Adj. Close'].shift(-forecast_out)

I'm using Python 3.6.4, if that's of any relevance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Keyerrors` are what you get when referring to a `dict()` like object and no `key` can be found in `dict`.  You redefine `df` many times in this program, which creates a new `df` object.  it does not alter the old one.  so when you say

```
df = df[['Adj. Open','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]
```

You are removing the `key` value of `Adj. Close`

Then you try to reference it later saying

```
df['label'] = df['Adj. Close'].shift(-forecast_out)
```

but `Adj Close` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Glad to help friend.  Also when you run into errors I recommend checking here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/exceptions for what the error means

Comment: Thanks for that too! I wish I could up vote your answer, but I've got only 1 reputation. :(

Comment: You can still select one answer per question as correct or "best". It pretty much does the same thing but also lets other members of the community know that you aren't looking for more answers

Answer (score 1):

In this line of your code:

```
df = df[['Adj. Open','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]
```

you are setting `df` to have only above columns. And later trying to access a key which is not present in your df

```
df['label'] = df['Adj. Close'].shift(-forecast_out)
```

Hence, the error.

Comment: I've got 1 reputation. Sorry!